# How to use sigPointsClicked in pyqtgraph

Tags: pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I created a plot with `pyqtgraph` that displays a line with points:

```
self.gaussianPlot = GraphicsLayoutWidget()
self.gaussianPlot.resize(750, 250)    

energyPlot=self.gaussianPlot.addPlot(row=1, col=1)
energyPlot.plot(self.scfenergies, symbol='o')
energyPlot.sigPointsClicked.connect(self.gausclicked())
```

I would like to detect which point on the `energyPlot` has been clicked. However, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/shrx/PycharmProjects/moldy/moldy.py", line 358, in readGaussian
energyPlot.sigPointsClicked.connect(self.gausclicked)
AttributeError: 'PlotItem' object has no attribute 'sigPointsClicked'
```

How to correctly use the `sigPointsClicked` to detect which point was clicked?

**UPDATE**

Following @Luke's answer, here's how I rewrote the code:

```
self.energyPlot=self.gaussianPlot.addPlot(row=1, col=1)
self.energyPlotData=self.energyPlot.plot(self.scfenergies, symbol='o')
self.energyPlotData.sigPointsClicked.connect(self.gausclicked)

def gausclicked(self, points):
    print(points)
    print(self.energyPlot.listDataItems())
```

As a result, I get:

```
<pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.PlotDataItem.PlotDataItem object at 0x7f1a18065678>
[<pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.PlotDataItem.PlotDataItem object at 0x7f1a18065678>]
```

So there is no apparent way that I can detect which point in the dataset was clicked? It looks like `sigPointsClicked` returns the whole data set.

**UPDATE 2**

The final fix needed was to add a second argument to the `gausclicked` function:

```
def gausclicked(self, item, points):
    print(points)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different classes you need to keep track of:

- **`PlotItem`** contains the entire plot area including the axes, viewbox, and all data contained within. This type is returned by `GraphicsLayoutWidget.addPlot()`. As the error indicates, it does not have `sigPointsClicked`.
- **`PlotDataItem`** is responsible for drawing the lines and points for a single dataset. This class has the `sigPointsClicked` signal and is returned when you call `PlotItem.plot(...)`.

Comment: Check the signature for the signal: http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/plotdataitem.html
The first argument sent is the `PlotDataItem` that was clicked; the second is the list of points.

Comment: Thanks, I read that documentation but it was not apparent to me that it also outputs the item that was clicked.